# UI Components - pass ids selection to listing selection

Tags: php, javascript, knockoutjs

How do i pass a selection of ids to an insert-listing component to preselect certain rows.

I have a dynamic rows component with entries related to the current product I'm editing. When click on a button to add more entries to the dynamic-rows component a modal open with an insert-listing component.

[image]
[image]

But the items from the dynamic-rows component are not selected in that listing.

How can I accomplish this?